# Socket I.O performance testing - multithreading tool

Tags: testing, socket.io, jmeter-plugins

Recently I am facing with troubles during testing of SocketIO server. I tried many tools, but no one works as I want.
I need to test server for many clients (like 50 users), send request and emit it to all connected. Then register time of sendind and receiving, count average times etc.

All features I need are guaranted by JMeter, but all plugins (e.g by Peter). I wasted a lot of time to examine what is wrong with my tests, but it turns that even samples from github don't work.

Postman is nice and simple, but unforntunately i can't have many clients on many threads. The same case we have with js libraries like Artillery.

How to test my socketIO server?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an alternative - [Gatling](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/gatling-installation) tool has [WebSocket support](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/websocket/)

JMeter doesn't have WebSocket support out of the box but there is a nice plugin - [JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/) which should be quite sufficient. It even provides [socket.io-chatserversample.jmx](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/samples/socket.io-chatserversample.jmx) test plan which you can use as a reference.

With regards to "Postman is nice and simple" - Postman [supports performance testing up to certain extent](https://blog.postman.com/postman-api-performance-testing/) (as long as browser plugin is suitable for performance testing). Also given you're capable of getting the expected behaviour using Postman you can use a sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the requests originating from Postman and JMeter and amend your JMeter configuration so its network footprint would be the same as Postman generates.

Comment: Postman doesn't let to test many requests for sockeio. It works only for http requests thus it is useless.